# How to make a page element static/hover above things that scroll under it (I already have a static background)

Tags: html, css, static, background-image

I am using SiteBuilder to make my website marsya.com, and I inserted a code snippet into the header & body of my page (I didn't know where it should go so I put it in both places) that allows me to have a fixed background image. Hooray!

The problem is, while my navigation bar & location info are where I want them when I am zoomed at 100%, if the zoom or screen size are different my nav bar & the rest of that table row get lost in background image.

I would like them to either stay static are relative to the background (my first choice) or to just stay at the top of the page and not scroll along with the rest of my content (second choice) (I tried to post images of what I am describing, but I don't have enough reputation points)

Help! Oh, and in case you hadn't guessed by my use of SiteBuilder (and the fact that I don't know if the background image goes in the header or body), I am not a programmer. So, if you could make your advice as clear and 101 as possible, I'd appreciate it :)

marsya.com

Answer (score 0):

To make an element not move along with rest of the page you need to add below styling to your .css file-

```
#ELEMENT-ID{
position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this section below (I assume you added this code for the background image):

```
<style>
body
{ 
background-image:url('http://www.marsya.com/images/background.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 
}
</style>
```

Change where it says:

```
background-position:center;
```

Change to

```
background-position:left top;
```

This will make the position fixed to the top left and the image won't resize when the browser is changed in size.